# Crear un registro para cada campo almacenado en una tabla temporal

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

tengo en siguiente query donde en una tabla temporal guardo todos los lunes entre un rango de fechas.

```
DECLARE @TEMP TABLE(REGISTRO DATE)
DECLARE @startdate datetime = '2017-01-19'
DECLARE @enddate datetime = '2017-02-19' ;with cte(col)
AS
(
SELECT @startdate
UNION ALL
SELECT col + 1
FROM cte
WHERE col <= @enddate
)
INSERT INTO @TEMP
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE DATEDIFF(dd,2,col)% 7 = 0
```

Obtengo una tabla con los resultados:

```
2017-01-25 
2017-02-01 
2017-02-08
2017-02-15
```

Ahora en una tabla real de mi base de datos necesito crar un registro para cada resultado obtenido
en este case seria INSERT para la tabla visita

```
INSERT INTO Visita (fecha) VALUES('2017-01-25')
INSERT INTO Visita (fecha) VALUES('2017-02-01')
INSERT INTO Visita (fecha) VALUES('2017-02-08')
INSERT INTO Visita (fecha) VALUES('2017-02-15')
```

Answer (score 1):

¿Por qué no insertar los datos directamente a tu tabla `Visita` sin pasar por una tabla temporal?

Modificando un poco tu script:

```
DECLARE @startdate datetime = '2017-01-19'
DECLARE @enddate datetime = '2017-02-19'

;with cte(col)
AS
(
SELECT @startdate
UNION ALL
SELECT col + 1
FROM cte
WHERE col <= @enddate
)
INSERT INTO Visita (fecha) -- directo a la tabla Visita
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE DATEDIFF(dd,2,col)% 7 = 0
```